# "The Audio Service is not running" Windows 8.1 Lenovo G500

Tags: audio, drivers, lenovo-laptop

A three month old Lenovo G500 laptop upgraded to Windows 8.1. Now there is no system or playback sound at all; have uninstalled Conexant HD Audio and then installed the latest drivers multiple times (5) with reboots each time. Nothing. I have now reinstalled the old driver that came with the machine. Still nothing!

Comment: How long as the sound not worked?

Comment: Windows 8 and 8.1 should be free as experimental software ;)

Comment: Ramhound - two days with no sound whatsoever, but before that intermittently on and off problems for six weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's complaining about services, then your best option is to look at the windows services.
Try opening your start menu, typing `services.msc` and hitting enter. This brings up the service management window. From here you can look for any audio related services that are disabled and enable them. After that restart your PC and see if it works. If it doesn't, disable it again and try any others.

Don't enable them all at once - go through them one by one until you find which one to keep. it is a long process, but keep in mind too many unnecessary services can really slow your PC down.

Comment: Thanks Jonah, I will do. Windows Audio will not start... the error message is "Windows could not start the Windows Audio Service. Error 0x800706cc: the endpoint is a duplicate"

Comment: Googling reveals that your antivirus may have mistaken the audio service executable for a virus. Try looking in your antivirus's quarantine.

Answer (score 2):

Finally! 
A number of people had the same problem and it was caused by AVG quarantining an audio file after the most recent Windows update. Restoring the files from the Virus Vault, and rebooting solved the problem. However, I inadvertently missed restoring some of the quarantined files having deleted them so my fix was to completely uninstall AVG, reboot, then back up my recents and do a system restore to before the update. And sound is back! Hope this helps others with the same issue. Thanks everyone for your help!